# How can I filter an Flutter List based on a field with an array value?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app on Flutter with a Firebase backend and I am stuck on querying a List where the value of a field is an array.

The documents are fetched from Firestore and mapped into a data model:

```
    class HItemsData {
     final bool attachment;
     final String body;
     final bool mandatory;
     final String title;
     final List position;

  HItemsData({
    required this.attachment,
    required this.body,
    required this.mandatory,
    required this.title,
    required this.position,

  });
}
```

I get the items into my widget:

```
final hItems = Provider.of<List<HItemsData>?>(context);
```

A simple filter would be:

```
    final data = hItems?.where((el) => el.mandatory == true).toList();
```

However, I would like to filter the List that I get from Firestore based on the position field.

The position looks something like the data sets below and I would like to return List of items for every document in which the position contains a certain value, like '1'. in the below, I should get "The First, and The Third"

```
attachment: true,
body: "The First",
mandatory: true,
position: ['1', '2', '3', '5'],
title: "One"

attachment: true,
body: "The Second",
mandatory: true,
position: ['9', '7', '3', '5'],
title: "Two"

attachment: false,
body: "The Third",
mandatory: true,
position: ['4', '3', '1', '5'],
title: "Three"
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to fetch only the first element of the list?

Comment: not the first element, any element in the list where the position values which is an array contains '1'

Comment: Did you see the `arrayContains` operation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_6?

Comment: Unfortunately that only works when filtering the query snapshot, and I can only use it once. After creating the list from the snapshot, that's where I am trying to filter now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final data = hItems?.where((el) => el.position.contains('1')).toList();
```

I think this should do it. It iterates through the position array elements and returns a true if it finds '1' in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
final data = hItems?.where((el) => (el.position.indexOf('1')>=0).toList();
```

You can check indexOf in a list and if an element is present it will return an index or else it will return -1.

Comment: It gives me this error The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'HItemsData'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.